# Can a bulk crystal have a spontaneous quadrupole moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, material-science

Crystals of polar space groups e.g. ferroelectrics can have a spontaneous electric dipole moment. Is it possible for a crystal to have a spontaneous electric quadrupole moment (and higher order terms of the multipole expansion)? If so, what are the symmetry requirements for such moments to arise?

Comment: For example: the unit cell of $\mathrm{Na}\,\mathrm{Cl}$ should have an uncompensated octupole moment, so a defectless table salt cube should have a fairly substantial electric octupole moment.

Comment: A friend found this paper on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07987.pdf . I'll look more into it tomorrow, but it seems like it has what I'm looking for.